# How can I change the text in just a part of my string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript string that contains the following:

```
data-href="/Admin/Edit?pk=0001I&amp;rk=50050055"
```

How can I change this string so the value of rk is changed to a value held in the string newRowKey? Not sure if it helps but the data format always looks like this with the rk followed by an = and then terminated with the "

Comment: Are you parsing HTML? I'm a bit confused. Can you show us the code.

Comment: `data-href="/Admin/Edit?pk=0001I&amp;rk=50050055"` is invalid JavaScript, so I'm pretty sure something is amiss

Comment: Show some code please, and are you using jQuery? if yes, .attr() can help

Comment: From where are you getting the rk number?Is it from database or html or random? If it is html, you can post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datahref="/Admin/Edit?pk=0001I&amp;rk=50050055";
```

to change it if your building the URL

```
datahref="/Admin/Edit?pk=0001I&amp;rk="+ newRowKey;
```

or replace it if you know the existing value

```
datahref.replace("50050055", newRowKey);
```

if you do not know the value of rk, but you know its last in the URL, you could use indexOf to find it.

```
datahref = datahref.substring(0,datahref.indexOf("rk=")+3) + newRowKey;
```

Comment: Seems like it would make sense, but `data-href` isn't a valid variable name in JavaScript, so @Anne isn't explaining things right.

Comment: Ah.  I bet thats his problem, i did not even pay attention to that, seemed like a simple question

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain this correctly. What's there after rk= could be any string of numbers. It could be rk=123"

Answer (score 1):

```
data_href.replace(/rk=.*$/,'rk=' + newRowKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want a regular expression to replace that rk.

```
newRowKey = 'XXXXXX'
s = 'Edit?pk=0001I&amp;rk=50050055';
s2 = s.replace(/(.*;)(rk=)(.*)(&|)/, '$1$2' + newRowKey)
alert( s + "\n" + s2 );

//2nd test
s = 'Edit?pk=0001I&amp;rk=50050055&';

s2 = s.replace(/(.*;)(rk=)(.*)(&|)/, '$1$2' + newRowKey)
alert( s + "\n" + s2 );
```

​demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/g3TjE/